# In Pine Script, how can you do something once per day, or keep track if something has been done yet that day?

Tags: unix-timestamp, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm working on a TradingView script (Pine) and i'm trying to use my Daily-bar strategy on the 5-minute chart.  To do this, I need to basically only check conditions once per day.

I can do this by having a boolean variable such as dailyCheck = false and set it to true when I run that code and then reset it on a new day.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?  From what I read in the pine manual it says you can get unix time...but I don't know how to work with this and I can't print anything except numbers in the form of plot, so I can't figure out how to tell when a new day has started.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Version 1

There are lots of ways to detect a change of day. The [*Session and time information*](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html) User Manual page shows a few.

I like detecting a change in the [`dayofweek`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_dayofweek) or [`dayofmonth`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_dayofmonth) built-in variables:

```
//@version=4
study("Once per Day")
var dailyTaskDone = false
newDay = change(dayofweek)
doOncePerDay = rising(close, 2)     // Your condition here.
dailyTaskDone := doOncePerDay or (dailyTaskDone and not newDay)

plotchar(newDay, "newDay", "▼", location.top, transp = 60)
plotchar(doOncePerDay, "doOncePerDay", "•", location.top, transp = 0)
bgcolor(dailyTaskDone ? color.orange : na)
```

[image]

### Version 2

Following Michel's comment, this uses a more robust detection of the day change:

```
//@version=4
study("Once per Day")
var dailyTaskDone = false
newDay = change(time("D"))
doOncePerDay = rising(close, 2)     // Your condition here.
dailyTaskDone := doOncePerDay or (dailyTaskDone and not newDay)

plotchar(newDay, "newDay", "▼", location.top, transp = 60)
plotchar(doOncePerDay, "doOncePerDay", "•", location.top, transp = 0)
bgcolor(dailyTaskDone ? color.orange : na)
```

And for the OP, a v3 version:

```
//@version=3
study("Once per Day v3")
dailyTaskDone = false
newDay = change(time("D"))
doOncePerDay = rising(close, 2)     // Your condition here.
dailyTaskDone := doOncePerDay or (dailyTaskDone[1] and not newDay)

plotchar(newDay, "newDay", "▼", location.top, transp = 60)
plotchar(doOncePerDay, "doOncePerDay", "•", location.top, transp = 0)
bgcolor(dailyTaskDone ? orange : na)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do it in v3?

Comment: Ohh dayofweek...I didn't even know that existed and I been using pine for a couple of years haha.  I think I got it now, these are all in v3 too :) TY!

Comment: Luc, it might happen that there no trades in a week (e.g. there were long holidays), so there won't be changes in `change(dayofweek)`. IMHO `change(time("D"))` is more precise here.

Comment: Ah y, see what you mean. Would require the holiday to start on one weekday and end on the preceding one, right? In that case `dayofmonth` would be more robust I guess, but I get your point. Thx for the info. Appreciate.